# get last name first in bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx

I want to produce a bibliography that has "last-name, initials" for each author.

I use Lyx with ...

```
enter code here`Document > Settings > Document Class: Article (Standard Class)
```

I have Document > Settings > Bibliography items set as ...

```
Style format: Basic (BibTeX);
Bibliography Style > Default BibTeX style: plain;
Bibliography Generation > Processor: Default
```

I tried adding the following to the LaTeX Preamble, but doing so did not work

```
...
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
```

I got a pair of error messages.

```
"Undefined control sequence" [with Description being:  \DeclareNameAlias
                      {author}{last-first}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.]
```

and

```
"LaTex Error: Missing \begin{document}" [with Description being:  \DeclareNameAlias{a
                        uthor}{last-first}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  **  to proceed.


If that doesn't work, type  X **  to quit.]
```

(Here, each ** denotes "< return >", but without the two spaces around the word return. Also, I do not know why the error message shows a break between the a and the u in "author." There does not seem to be a problem with the work "author" in the material that I typed into LyX.)

I know very little about TeX, LaTeX, etc. My system uses MiKTeX (but I do not know how to use it directly). I use JabRef to maintain a list of articles. I do not know how to install new 'packages' for use by LyX (but might be able to follow detailed directions).

I hope that someone will provide a simple solution.

Comment: You are using BibTeX (Style format: Basic (BibTeX)), but `\DeclareNameAlias` is a `biblatex` command. (BibTeX and `biblatex` are incompatible, you can only use one of the two). `biblatex` users should note that `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}` is deprecated, it should be `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}` on current systems.

Comment: @MIco Thanks. Based on your answer, I plan to ask the journal to do the seemingly only thing that I cannot do - that is, convert {regarding the bibliography} author names from "given family" to "family, initials". Based on your answer, an answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532741/how-to-make-and-install-a-lyx-document-class-based-on-a-journal-s-latex-templat/532791#532791, and correspondence with the journal, this seems like a possible path forward. Again, appreciated.